# Linux X86_64 physical memory layout

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, memory

As per the Linux kernel documentation `https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/boot.txt`, there is a kernel real mode code from `X+10000` to `X+08000`. There are two question I have;

```
For a modern bzImage kernel with boot protocol version >= 2.02, a
memory layout like the following is suggested:

    ~                        ~
        |  Protected-mode kernel |
100000  +------------------------+
    |  I/O memory hole   |
0A0000  +------------------------+
    |  Reserved for BIOS     |  Leave as much as possible unused
    ~                        ~
    |  Command line      |  (Can also be below the X+10000 mark)
X+10000 +------------------------+
    |  Stack/heap        |  For use by the kernel real-mode code.
X+08000 +------------------------+  
    |  Kernel setup      |  The kernel real-mode code.
    |  Kernel boot sector    |  The kernel legacy boot sector.
X       +------------------------+
    |  Boot loader       |  <- Boot sector entry point 0000:7C00
001000  +------------------------+
    |  Reserved for MBR/BIOS |
000800  +------------------------+
    |  Typically used by MBR |
000600  +------------------------+ 
    |  BIOS use only     |
000000  +------------------------+
```

1.Is the real mode code is part of GRUB or it is part of bzImage.
2.If the real mode code is in between `X+10000` to `X+08000` where is the physical location of the `long mode/64 bit` mode kernel code?

Comment: Note that the real mode code is unused if the machine is booted with UEFI firmware (unless in BIOS compatibility mode). This is a quite common scenario in 2020.

Answer (score 0):

(I’ll refer to the latest version of [the boot protocol documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/boot.html), the document you looked at is old.)

The real-mode kernel boot sector and setup code are part of the kernel; see [section 1.2](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/boot.html#the-real-mode-kernel-header). They live between *X* and *X*+0x08000.

The protected-mode kernel is loaded at 0x100000, it’s the first item in the table above.